# Working SQL query generates "A RunSQL statement requires an argument consisting of an SQL statement" in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to make a form in Access with a "search as you type" function to find a customer.
I'll double click the correct match in a listbox to update the customer info textboxes.

I succeeded the "search as you type" part, but not the listbox double click update form part.

I get the following RunSQL error:

> "A RunSQL statement requires an argument consisting of an SQL statement"

The SQL statement works in a query.

```vb
Private Sub lstClient_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim selectedItem, strSQL, strSQL1 As String
    Dim i As Integer
        
    i = lstClient.ListIndex
    selectedItem = lstClient.ItemData(i)
    txtCustName.Value = selectedItem
        
    strSQL = "SELECT tblClient.[Addresse] FROM tblClient WHERE tblClient.[Nom] ='" & selectedItem & "';"

    strSQL1 = "SELECT tblClient.[Addresse] FROM tblClient WHERE tblClient.[Nom] ='Bernache Funeral home';"
            
    DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL1)
    Text191.Value = strSQL1
End Sub
```

The second statement (strSQL1) is the one I tried in the query to make sure it worked, and it did.

Comment: `RunSQL` is for updates, inserts, and deletes.  You want to open a recordset or use some other mechanism to select data.

Comment: By using the other guy's code and removing the RunSQL statement, I got it to work now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL1)
Text191.Value = rs.Fields("Addresse").Value

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: I get a new error msg: "Ms Access DB engine cannot find the input table or query. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly"

Comment: I had to remove the RunSQL line and do some modifications, but it's working now. Thanks a lot! The solution was so hard to find on Google... I tried many resources "MS access SQL in VBA" and stuff like that.
Thanks!

Comment: Is it wrong to not put .Value at the end of "Text191.Value = rs.Fields("Addresse").Value"??
It works without right now